# Gaussian random variable: Probability that Y>value and variance given resistance - have I done correctly?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The questions are about Gaussian random variables. I have DC supply voltage represented by a random variable Y. The voltage should not be much higher than the intended operating voltage for any extended period of time.

DC supply variance is 0.1 V^2 when operating at 10 V

a) What is P[X>10.65]
b)The supply is connected to two resistances, R1 = 10Ogm and R2 = 40 Ohm, they are connected in series. What is the variance of voltage across R2?

Concerning a) I use Z = (X - mu)/sigma = 1.732
P[Z>1.732] = 0.0418 - The book says that the answer should be 0.02
Concerning b) I do this Var(V2) = R2^2 * Var(Y) / (R1 + R2)^2
and get answer 0.007 while answer should be 0.006

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome. It's a good idea to make your title more specific so users who can help *know* from the main menu that they can help

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for your feedback, I hope to have made title more specific

Comment: @Gonçalo I have updated my question more, they are in series.

Comment: @Gonçalo I have used the root square. I have done Z like this: Z = (10.65 - 10) / 0.3162 = 1.67.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you, it's now giving correct value!